# Kernel APIs or using APIs in the kernel

Tags: winapi, kernel

I'd like to know if and how I can access API calls inside the kernel. I need them to preform several integrity checks on a program of mine running in user mode. But I don't know how I can access the APIs and functions required to do so.

How do I obtain the process id of my user mode process? And how do I access all its memory to preform the check?

PS: I'm on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: win32 kernel, linux kernel , some other kernel ?

Comment: O right sorry, I'm so stupid sometimes. This question applies to the win32 kernel. I'm sorry for not mentioning that (on a windows xp machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by creating a kernel mode driver and then communicating with your user mode process from the kernel space. You can refer [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/KM-UMGuide.doc) for detailed information.

Comment: If you are using windows XP with service pack 3, you can go for a filter driver (Filter drivers are not supported in WIN XP SP2 and below). Filter drivers are a bit easy to understand and implement but they have certain limitations (that are not with legacy drivers) but are good for most of the general call hooking stuffs.